# JDBC java.sql.SQLException When Inserting Converted Enum Value to MySql Smallint Column

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-jdbc, enumeration

I'm trying to use an enum to display human readable values for a "permission" field (READ, WRITE, etc).  When I store the record in the associated MySQL table, the permission enum field needs to be converted to the associated integer (1, 2, 4, etc).  When I run the SpringBoot app and call the POST endpoint, I'm getting a strange SQL exception, though.  Here is the exception:

**Failed to execute DbAction.InsertRoot(entity=Invite(id=null, createdAt=2020-09-19 18:12:01, createdBy=1, listId=8, token=c3b95dc9-ec4d-4dde-a461-b12746afa61e, expiresAt=2020-09-26 18:12:01, permission=2), generatedId=null)] with root cause
java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect integer value: 'WRITE' for column 'permission' at row 1
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]**

It seems strange to me that the db action would report that the "permission" field to be inserted is a 2, yet the SQL exception is reporting that "WRITE" is not a valid integer value.  Any idea what I might be missing?

Here's the notable code and config.  Please note that I'm using JDBC and not JPA:

Here's the enum class:

```
public enum Permission {
    READ(1), WRITE(2), CREATE(4), DELETE(8), ADMIN(16);

    private Integer value;

    Permission(final Integer value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Integer getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    //@JsonCreator
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.getValue().toString();
    }

    //@JsonValue
    public static Permission forValue(final String name) {
        return Permission.valueOf(name);
    }
}
```

Here the POJO/Entity:

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.ToString;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@ToString
public class Invite {

    public static final int TOKEN_MINIMUM_LENGTH = 36;
    public static final int TOKEN_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = 40;

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String createdAt;

    private String createdBy;

    private Long listId;

    private String token;

    private String expiresAt;

    private Permission permission;

}
```

Here's the JdbcCustomConversions.  It should be noted that the ReadingConverter appears to be tripped when debugging but the WritingConverter does not.  I'm not sure if that is part of the problem or not.

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.data.convert.ReadingConverter;
import org.springframework.data.convert.WritingConverter;
import org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.JdbcCustomConversions;
import org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.config.AbstractJdbcConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.config.EnableJdbcRepositories;
import java.util.Arrays;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class JdbcConfiguration extends AbstractJdbcConfiguration {

    /**
     * JDBC Custom Conversions.
     *
     */
    @Override
    public JdbcCustomConversions jdbcCustomConversions() {
        return new JdbcCustomConversions(Arrays.asList(PermissionToInteger.INSTANCE, IntegerToPermission.INSTANCE));
    }

    // I have never seen this get tripped
    @WritingConverter
    enum PermissionToInteger implements Converter<Permission, Integer> {

        INSTANCE;

        @Override
        public Integer convert(final Permission permission) {
            return permission == null ? null : permission.getValue();
        }
    }

    // this one trips in the debugger and appears to be working fine
    @ReadingConverter
    enum IntegerToPermission implements Converter<Integer, Permission> {

        INSTANCE;

        @Override
        public Permission convert(final Integer code) {
            for (final Permission perm: Permission.values()) {
                if (perm.getValue().equals(code)) {
                    return perm;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the simple Repository:

```
import org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.query.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

public interface InviteRepository extends CrudRepository<Invite, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT * from invite where token = :token")
    Optional<Invite> findByToken(String token);

    @Query("SELECT * from invite where created_by = :userId")
    List<Invite> findByUserId(Long userId);

    @Query("SELECT * from invite where list_id = :wishlistId")
    List<Invite> findByWishlistId(Long wishlistId);

}
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Aaron

Comment: You need to use `@Enumerated` annotation. Here you can find article about this: [How to map an Enum to a database column](https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tips-map-enum-database-column/)  and also this one: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-persisting-enums-in-jpa

Answer (score 1):

The fix was to change the WritingConverter to String instead of Integer:

```
@WritingConverter
public enum PermissionToInteger implements Converter<Permission, String> {

    INSTANCE;

    @Override
    public String convert(final Permission permission) {
        return permission == null ? null : permission.getValue().toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some debugging source code of spring jdbc, it can covert the enum type to integer by target class is assign from JdbcValue class.

````kotlin
   @Bean
   override fun jdbcCustomConversions() = JdbcCustomConversions(arrayListOf(
        @WritingConverter
        object: Converter<LoginTypes, JdbcValue> {
            override fun convert(p0: LoginTypes) = JdbcValue.of(p0.code,JDBCType.INTEGER)
        },
        @ReadingConverter
        object:Converter<Int,LoginTypes>{
            override fun convert(p0: Int): LoginTypes? = LoginTypes.values().first { it.code==p0 }
        }```
````